# How to load an image on button click?

Tags: javascript, image, button, toggle, visibility

I'm kind of new to HTML / Javascript, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it so when I click a button, an image loads. This is all I can come up with, but then again I am very bad with this stuff, and I am still learning *greatly*.

```
<html>
<div style="visibility:invisible" id="theTrick">
<img id="myImage" src="https://minecraft.net/images/logo.png" alt="Test">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction">Click for the Minecraft Logo</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById="theTrick".style = "visibility:initial"

}
</script>
</html>
```

## EDIT

I have solved this, and since then learned a LOT more, mastering HTML and CSS, and now learning the works of JavaScript. I do have a question though to add on to this; is there a way to have the image disappear on another click, then reappear on the next click, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. It's `visibility: hidden`, not `visibility: invisible`.
2. It's `myFunction()`, not `myFunction`.
3. It's `document.getElementById("theTrick")`, not `document.getElementById = "theTrick"`.
4. It's `visibility: visible`, not `visibility: initial` (the initial visibility is `hidden`, which you've set at the top).

You may find [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) on the CSS `visibility` property useful.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/34MhC/)

Comment: There's also some supporting documentation which might help [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

Comment: Thanks, and can I get a demo on how I would be able to click the button again to have it reset?

Comment: @user3799724 Just reverse all of the style attributes to their `visibility` counterparts. You may also want to look at the [jQuery `hide` function](http://api.jquery.com/hide).